# is there any tutorial exist for calling web service in android through ksoap 2.5.4?

Tags: android-ksoap2

friends,

i want to call webservice using ksoap 2.5.4(or latest) library any one guide me whats is the procedure of using it or any link of tutorial?

and one more thing is there request timeout related implementation exists in it?

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try looking here: [Basic KSOAP Android Tutorial](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/2010/11/basic-ksoap-android-tutorial.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have provided a few tutorials on using kSOAP with Android. I hope one of them helps.

http://roderickbarnes.com/blog/category/technology/web-services-technology

It is very important that you understand the big picture before just using the APIs. The comments in my code should shed a little light on the bigger idea.